# Iterate through an array or hashes to find a key in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I keep find only answers that iterate through an array of hashes to find a particular value. I want to iterate through an array of hashes to find a key. I am trying to access the key :labels. The array changes length and position of elements each time, so i cannot rely on a hardcoded index. Here is my array:

```
array = [
 {:status=>"100", 
  :status_msg=>"OUT_OF_ZONE", :order_ref=>"S", :order_id=>"28704622",
  :price=>"0", :"@xsi:type"=>"tns:Result"},
 {:status=>"100", 
  :status_msg=>"OUT_OF_ZONE", :order_ref=>"4", :order_id=>"28704623",
  :price=>"0", 
  :labels=>{:label_str=>"**%*%"}}
]
```

Comment: I don't see your iteration code. Hint: it looks like you could use `detect` here.

Comment: yeah, i guess `array.detect { |hash| hash.has_key? :labels }` is it

Comment: `find` and `key?`:)

Comment: Thanks @maxpleaner that did it, didnt realize that i could use an enumerable

Comment: Is there only one `:labels` key in your array? If not are you only interested in the first one?

Comment: Only interested in the first one as there are only repeats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby 2.3+ you can use `Hash#dig` which returns the value of a nested key or nil.

`labels = array.map{ |h| h.dig(:labels)}.compact`

`.compact` is added only to remove nil entries. Leave off if you want to keep the same size array.